How to set panel title and display name from my query in Grafana?
just worked a little bit with Grafana already but I got stuck at the naming of my gauge visualization.
What I'm trying to achieve is, that the panel title under Panel Options is created from my SQL queries value.
Same for the value that is visualized.
In the picture you see the panel title as school and below the visualized value you see classroom.
School should be a value from my queries. The same goes for the classroom. At the moment I can only set the panel title static and where you see static classroom as well is normally the row name from where the value is from.
What I tried so far:
I tried my luck with $__cell_N but the only result I got is that the see now $__cell_N in the title.
I checked already this link: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-data-links/
Nothing I tried really worked.
Does anyone have an idea how I can change this? Or maybe this is not possible by design. Any help is appreciated ;-).
Best regards

Use dashboard variable, where you prepare panel title - dashboard variables can be used in the panel title (panel query)

try  "title": "${Your Variable Name}" in the panel json

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
